# Break a zip file into INDIVIDUAL pieces

Tags: zip, binaryfiles, file-manipulation

What I am trying to do is this;

I get these zip files from clients which are 1.5gb in general. They all include pictures only. I need to make them into 100mb files to actually upload it to my server. Problem is that, If I break my 1.5gb zip file, I need to re-attach all of them if I need to use one.

When I break the 1.5gb zip file into a 100mb zip file, I need the 100mb one to act as a separate new file so the server will unzip it and upload the pictures into the database. I have looked for this problem but most of the threads are about how to split a zip file. This is partially what I want to do and I can do it now but I also need those smaller pieces to be able to unzip on its own. Is it possible to break a zip file into smaller pieces that will act as a new, stand alone zip files?

Thanks.

Comment: what language/framework are you into?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question. I think unzip in the Linux shell cannot handle a zip file larger than 1 GB, and I need to unzip them unattended in a headless NAS. What I do for now is unzip everything in the desktop HD, select files until they almost reach 1 GB, archive and delete them, then select the next set of files until I reach 1 GB.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is not clear, but I will try to answer it based upon my understanding of your dilemma.

### Questions

1. Why does the file size need to be limited?

   - Is it the transfer to the server that is the constraining factor?
   - Is application (on the server) unable to process files over a certain size?
2. Can the process be altered so that image file fragments can be recombined on the server before processing?
3. What operating systems are in use on the client and the server?
4. Do you have shell access to the server?

### A few options

- Use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) to reduce the files so they fit within the file size constraints
- On Linux/Mac, this is relatively straightforward to do:

  1. `split -b 1m my_large_image.jpg` (you need the `b` parameter for it to work on binary files)
  2. Compress each file into its own zip
  3. Upload to the server
  4. Unzip
  5. Concatenate the fragments back into an image file:

  `cat xaa xab xac xad (etc) > my_large_image.jpg`